# Inequality $\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{y^3}{y^2+z^2}+\frac{z^3}{z^2+x^2} \geqslant \frac{x+y+z}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, sum-of-squares-method, tangent-line-method

Help to prove this Inequality:

If  x,y,z are postive real numbers then:

$\dfrac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}+\dfrac{y^3}{y^2+z^2}+\dfrac{z^3}{z^2+x^2} \geqslant \dfrac{x+y+z}{2}$

I tied to use analytic method with convex function but no result:

Since $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is a convex function, by Jensen we obtain:
$$\frac{1}{x+y+z}\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x}{x+y+z}\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2}}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\frac{x}{x+y+z}\cdot\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2}\right)}=\frac{x+y+z}{\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(x+\frac{y^2}{x}\right)}.$$ 
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$\frac{x+y+z}{\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(x+\frac{y^2}{x}\right)}\geq\frac{1}{2}$$ or
$$x+y+z\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{y^2}{x},$$ which is wrong.

thanks

Comment: What have you tried? "Nothing" or "I am completely lost" are unacceptable answers. If you are lost, at least articulate what specifically might be tripping you up on techniques you might have considered trying.

Comment: @samad I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: I tied to use analytic method with convex function but no  result

Comment: Please type up all of your scratch work, don't just describe what you did in a comment.

Comment: @samad Show please, how exactly you worked with convex function.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg That is a really nice edit you made to the question 

Comment: @Maximilian Janisch I am sure that the topic starter meant this way. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [symetric inequality for a rational function of three variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932146/symetric-inequality-for-a-rational-function-of-three-variables)

Answer (score 6):

Hint: We have $$ \frac {x^3}{x^2 + y^2}=x-\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2}\ge x-\frac{y}{2}$$ because by AM-GM $x^2+y^2\geq 2xy$ so that $$\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\le\frac12$$

Answer (score 4):

We apply AM-GM Inequality with $x^2 + y^2 \geq 2xy$.
\begin{align*}
&\dfrac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}+\dfrac{y^3}{y^2+z^2}+\dfrac{z^3}{z^2+x^2} \\
&= \dfrac{x^3 + xy^2}{x^2+y^2}+\dfrac{y^3 + yz^2}{y^2+z^2}+\dfrac{z^3 + zx^2}{z^2+x^2} - \left(\dfrac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2}+\dfrac{yz^2}{y^2+z^2}+\dfrac{zx^2}{z^2+x^2}\right) \\
&= x + y + z - \left(\dfrac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2}+\dfrac{yz^2}{y^2+z^2}+\dfrac{zx^2}{z^2+x^2}\right) \\
&\geq x + y + z - \left(\dfrac{xy^2}{2xy}+\dfrac{yz^2}{2yz}+\dfrac{zx^2}{2xz}\right) \\
&= x + y + z - \left(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{y}{2} + \frac{z}{2}\right) \\
&= \frac{x + y + z}{2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{x+y+z}{2}=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{x}{2}\right)=\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^3-xy^2}{2(x^2+y^2)}=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x^3-xy^2}{2(x^2+y^2)}-\frac{x-y}{2}\right)=\sum_{cyc}\frac{y(x-y)^2}{2(x^2+y^2)}\geq0.$$